# How to add a new object to a json api from front-end in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to add a new object to an existing json api. What are the easy ways to add new object to the api from front-end.

```
 componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/v4/adminv2/web.php/client-onboard/family-management/api/editFamilies')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    const family = this.getFamilyInfo(result);
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        items: result,
                        familyName: family['name'],
                        familyId: family['id'],
                        familyCodes: family['clientcodes'],
                    });
                },
);
}

handleShow = () => {
        this.setState({ isOpen: true,
        });
        this.state.items.push({ client_count: 1,
            clientcodes: this.state.clientcode,
            family_name: this.state.newFamilyName,
            id: 2 });
        // add this new item to json api
    }
```

I could add the new object in the front-end but this is not changing the api data in the back-end.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: `this.state.items` never modify state by hands, always use setState, no exceptions here.

Answer (score 1):

never mutate `state` directly, alway use `setState`. Try something like this and let me know

```
handleShow = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => { 
          isOpen: true,
          items: {
            ...prevState.items,
            { 
              client_count: 1,
              clientcodes: this.state.clientcode,
              family_name: this.state.newFamilyName,
              id: 2 
            }
          }
        });
           // add this new item to json api
    }
```